# Should i buy a midi keyboard or a standard keyboard to learn?

Tags: practice, keyboard

i am brand new to music production and i want to start with learning keyboard.
So my question is shall i buy a midi keyboard or a standard keyboard to learn.
i am total beginner..
is there a difference between Midi keyboard and standard keyboard?
thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site Marc. By 'standard keyboard', do you mean a keyboard that has its own build-in sounds (as opposed to a MIDI 'controller keyboard' that only sends MIDI messages)?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you start by looking at the question [Using keyboard/MIDI controller to learn piano](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6302/using-keyboard-midi-controller-to-learn-piano).

My answer: if you want something self contained to play on and produce a sound, get a keyboard or digital piano which has some good sounds built and speakers built in. You can just switch it on and start playing anytime you like.

If you want to use just a computer or a synth module to get the sounds, you might prefer to get just a controller. This has some sort of MIDI output (usually USB MIDI these days) and it also needs a computer (or a synth unit of some sort), plus an amplifier and speakers, to get sound. To play you probably need to switch on and plug in more "stuff" each time, unless you can have it all set up permanently.

In other words, the controller keyboard doesn't have any sounds or speakers built in and needs other equipment to get started (which you may already have).

To make things more confusing, a lot of the keyboards have speakers built in but also have MIDI output so they can be plugged into a computer as well.