# What variety of song can be played on a 22 white keys - keyboard?

Tags: piano, beginner

I don't know much about pianos but I want to learn to play a few songs. I have an old keyboard with 22 white keys which I will label... Can I play most normal songs on this keyboard or does it become limited with only 22 keys?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using keyboard/MIDI controller to learn piano](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6302/using-keyboard-midi-controller-to-learn-piano)

Comment: Your keyboard has **only** white keys? If tere are black ones as well, there's really no need to label them - there's a distinct pattern - for example, there's always a D note between the two black keys - meaning there's C to its left and E to its right. Only 4 othrers to find!

Comment: Example(s) of what you think of as a "normal song" would help. We can probably give you more specific answers if we know the kind of music you might like to play.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of melodies have a range of around 1 and 1/2 or 2 octaves. Your keyboard seems to have three octaves. You should be able to play many songs, but some things to consider...

- You might need to transpose some songs to get them to better fit the limited range of your keyboard.
- If a part of the melody goes too high, you can try dropping it down one octave.
- Make changes to the accompaniment to keep it in your keyboard range. If you have to choose between changing the melody or accompaniment, try changing the accompaniment first.

Answer (score 0):

By 22 white keys I’m assuming you mean a 3 octave keyboard. That means aside from the white keys you have 3 alternating sets of 2 and 3 black keys for a total of 37 notes. Correct me if I’m wrong.

This type of keyboard is fine for playing melodies with simple chords or chords and bass and you can have fun playing it if you accept its  main limitation, which is range. You can only play so low or so high on this keyboard before running out of room because of the relatively low number of notes it has. Most basic keyboards have 61 keys or 5 octaves and a piano or full sized keyboard has 88 keys. This gives you the ability to play more comfortably and not run out of notes as you go up or down.

By all means try it out, you may find that it’s enough for you to get started. Down the road you can invest in a better keyboard with more notes and nice sounds for anywhere between $100 and $200.

Answer (score 0):

You can play the tune of any song, and add some sort of accompaniment.   You'll be limited when trying to play sheet music literally though.

Please don't label the keys.